# slideDown() with fixed div and pushing the rest of the content

Tags: jquery, css

> My goal is to slide down/up a `div` by clicking on an element. I wish when the `div` slides down/up the content below also moves down/up. I also want this `div` stays fixed when the page is scrolled.

Here is my try...

HTML:

```
 <div id="slidebox">Some content</div>
 <div id="wrap">Some content <input type="button" id="btn" value="Show Div"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#slidebox{
 height:100px;
 display:none;
 position:relative;
 background:red;
}

#wrap{
 height:1000px;
 background:green;
 position:relative;
}

#btn{
 position:absolute;
 top:100px;
 left:0px;
}
```

JQuery:

```
  $("#btn").click(function(){
                 if ($("#slidebox").is(":hidden")){
                     $("#slidebox").slideDown(1500);
                 }else{
                     $("#slidebox").slideUp(1500);
                 }                  
            });
```

I achieved the first goal. The `wrap` is pushed by the `slidebox`. But when the page is scrolled the `slidebox` doesn't stay fixed. I tried changing the position attribute on both `divs`, but they start to have an undesirable behavior.
What can I do to achieved the desire effect? Thanks.

Comment: So you want all the content to be fixed? Or only the slide box?

Comment: @NiekNijland only the `slidebox`.

Comment: So, why do you want the content below the div to move down or up when the div is of a fixed position? To me this moving behaviour combinated with the fixed behaviour sounds impossible :/

Comment: @NiekNijland the goal is to make a fixed header that expands without overlaps the content that is below.

Comment: Ahh, got it! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a class on if scroll position from top is bigger than `x`, class which will add `position: fixed;` to the `#slidebox` element:

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
  if ($("#slidebox").is(":hidden")) {
    $("#slidebox").slideDown(1500);
  } else {
    $("#slidebox").slideUp(1500);
  }

});
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $("#slidebox").toggleClass('fixed', $(window).scrollTop() > 10);
})
```

```css
#slidebox {
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  z-index: 1;
}

#slidebox.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#wrap {
  height: 1000px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
}

#btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slidebox">Some content 1</div>
<div id="wrap">Some content 2<input type="button" id="btn" value="Show Div"></div>
```

Comment: It works! Thanks. The only thing is the width of `slidebox` has to be set to 100%.

Comment: @João, I'm glad it works for you. I've added `width: 100%` to `slidebox` element. Please see the updated answer. I've also added a shorthand code for the add class solution when scrolling.

Comment: Wrap the `#slidebox` element in a wrapper with the same height. This way when you start scrolling the page won't jump. See my answer :)

Comment: @NiekNijland, sorry but I don't see any difference between the way it acts and please do not copy my code to add it in your answer. And I'm reffering to this exact replica `$(window).scroll(function() {
  $("#slidebox").toggleClass('fixed', $(window).scrollTop() > 10);
})`. That wasn't the question the OP asked. I think João found the answer he was looking for.

Comment: @Ionut in your example when you start scrolling, the green divs schoots 100px up. In my example it doesn't. And sorry I should've mentionend I copied your answer! Will give you credits in my answer :)

Comment: @NiekNijland, ok, you are right about that, good touch, but the original question wasn't about that. Maybe he already had a div wrapping that element. I don't think the code from the question is the whole code he has. Anyway, I hope that helps João too.

Comment: @Ionut ofcourse it is... You don't want the content to shoot underneath the sticky header when you start scrolling on a page, do you? Anyways I think João question is answered

Answer (score 0):

I'm using chrome to view this.. When I scroll, do you want me to be able to close the div?

```
   <head>
        <script src="js/currentjquery.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
                    $('#slidebox').css({
                        'display' : 'none'
                    });
                }
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            #slidebox {
                height: 100px;
                display: none;
                position: relative;
                background: red;
            }

            #wrap {
                height: 1000px;
                background: green;
                position: relative;
            }

            #btn {
                position: absolute;
                top: 100px;
                left: 0px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="slidebox">
            Some content
        </div>
        <div id="wrap">
            Some content 2
            <input type="button" id="btn" value="Show Div">
        </div>
        <script>
            $("#btn").click(function() {
                if ($("#slidebox").is(":hidden")) {
                    $("#slidebox").slideDown(1500);
                } else {
                    $("#slidebox").slideUp(1500);
                }
            });

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, the `slidebox` will only close (slideUp) if the user click on the button again. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Copied answer of @Ionut. Credits to him/her :)

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
  if ($("#slidebox").is(":hidden")) {
    $("#slidebox").slideDown(1500);
    $(".slidebox-wrapper").slideDown(1500);
  } else {
    $("#slidebox").slideUp(1500);
    $(".slidebox-wrapper").slideUp(1500);
  }

});
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $("#slidebox").toggleClass('fixed', $(window).scrollTop() > 10);
})
```

```css
.slidebox-wrapper {
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
}

#slidebox {
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  z-index: 1;
}

#slidebox.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#wrap {
  height: 1000px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
}

#btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slidebox-wrapper">
    <div id="slidebox">Some content 1</div>
</div>
<div id="wrap">Some content 2<input type="button" id="btn" value="Show Div"></div>
```